# Background static when sending audio to stereo receiver via bluetooth

Tags: sound, xubuntu, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I'm running xubuntu on my HP laptop. I have a bluetooth stereo receiver, and I use my laptop to send audio to the receiver from my laptop via bluetooth. When I do this, there is a constant static background noise. I have tested the stereo via bluetooth with a windows machine, and there is no static. I have also plugged my xubuntu laptop directly into the stereo via rca, and there is no static. Is there a problem with bluetooth in xubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by a lack of support for your specific Bluetooth adapter in the os. I hate to tell people that in order to fix their problem they have to pay money but you need a different adapter that has better Linux support. Comment on this if you would like to know which are the best Bluetooth adapters for Linux.

Comment: Currently, I'm using a Panda Bluetooth 4.0 USB Nano Adapter, which I purchased specifically because Amazon says the adapter supports Ubuntu. They're right. It does. But the sound is full of static. It could very well be that I need a more expensive adapter. Panda works, but produces much static.

Comment: I agree a more expensive one may be needed. I am an audiophile and I would recommend staying away from Bluetooth at all costs in high end systems.

Answer (score 0):

I purchased a Belkin Mini Bluetooth v4.0 Adapter. It works perfectly with xubunutu 14.04. No static. The OS detected it instantly, so there was no setup necessary. The Panda adapter produced static, but the Belkin does not. Problem solved!